# Apply multiples conditions with Doctrine Query Language

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql, doctrine-query

In my database, i have a column "refused", she can have 0 or 1 or NULL value.

I want to get only rows with 0 and NULL values.

I tried this :

```
->andWhere('b.refused IS NULL')
```

It's okay, but if i want to get the 0 values too that's not working :

```
->andWhere('b.refused = 0')
```

Anyone know how do this or how to don't get any rows where there is "1" ?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need **AND**. It is **OR** because you want either NULL **or** 0. Also `b.refused != 1` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to only get 0 OR NULL values, or your could get all elements not equals to 1 so do :

```
->where($qb->expr()->isNull('b.refused'));
->orWhere('b.refused = 0')
```

Comment: I have some errors with "IS" :  > "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 317: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IS'"

Comment: I tried "=" but new error : 
> Error: Expected Literal, got 'NULL'

Comment: I edited my answer, be sure to replace $qb by your query builder variable